# how do you convert df to json file with numbers as number

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a data frame to a json format. This is my data frame called x:

```
structure(list(Desc = c("Web", "Mobile", "TV", "Store"), Total = c(223786915, 
42053151, 232299534, 26317530), Name = c("Total Login", "Total Login", 
"Total Login", "Total Login")), .Names = c("Desc", "Total", "Name"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

this is the function:

```
servers <- split(x,x$Name)
dumFun <- function(x){
  sData <- servers[x][[1]]
  if(nrow(sData) >0){
    # create appropriate list
    dumList <- unname(apply(sData[,c(1,as.numeric(2))], 1, function(y) unname(as.list(y))))
    return(toJSON(list(name = x, data = dumList))) 
  }
}
jsData <- lapply(names(servers), dumFun)
jsInd <- sapply(jsData, is.null)
p<-paste(jsData[!jsInd], collapse = ',')
p<-paste('[', p, ']')
```

It is treating x$Total as string. I need x$Total to be number and don't have double quotes around it. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Does `jsonlite` do what you want?

For example you can do `jsonlite::toJSON(x)`

```
res <- jsonlite::toJSON(x, pretty=TRUE)
cat(res)

[
{
    "Desc" : "Web",
    "Total" : 223786915,
    "Name" : "Total Login"
},
{
    "Desc" : "Mobile",
    "Total" : 42053151,
    "Name" : "Total Login"
},
{
    "Desc" : "TV",
    "Total" : 232299534,
    "Name" : "Total Login"
},
{
    "Desc" : "Store",
    "Total" : 26317530,
    "Name" : "Total Login"
}
]
```